# Interacting with contracts – automaticly setting an address on deployment

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

I have 2 contracts that can interact with each other:

```
contract ContractFoo {
  address private _contractBarAddress;

  constructor() {

  }

  function setContractBarAddress(address _address) public onlyOwner {
    _contractBarAddress = _address;
  }

  function doSomething() public {
    console.log("Bar is called");
    Bar(_contractBarAddress).helloWorld();
  }
}

contract Bar is Ownlable {

  constructor() {}

  function helloWorld() external {
    // Possible check if it is the Foo calling it
    console.log("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

Right now, after each deployment, I have to call `setContractBarAddress` to interact with `Bar`. **Is there a way one could set it automatically directly in solidity?** Right now the only way to automate is to write a custom function in e.g. Hardhat scripts to call such function.

Answer (score 2):

yes. deploy bar from ContractFoo and you have an object for the deployed contract.

something like

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.14;

//if bar in another file
import "./Bar.sol"

contract ContractFoo {

    Bar contractBar;

        constructor () {
            contractBar = new Bar;
        }

    contractBar.doNothing();
}


contract Bar {
    function doNothing() public pure {
            
    }
}
```